# How to add hidden utm parameters as custom field in Woocommerce check out

Tags: php, woocommerce, webhooks

I want to track utm from url/cookie and and pass them into Woocommerce order custom fields to use in a webhook.

I reference this post: [Adding UTM parameters to Woocommerce order information (Meta box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761283/adding-utm-parameters-to-woocommerce-order-information-meta-box?newreg=cde95d44177046d888f0d17aa8dde3c8)

However, instead of meta box I would like to actually generate customer field of utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign so that I can look up the data quickly via the webhook meta later. Anyone can show me how I can do that with a function.php snippet?

Thank you.

TLDR: I'm not sure how to create custom fields for the utms for Woocommerce checkout